# Let $G$ be a simple graph on $10$ vertices and $38$ edges. Prove that $G$ contains $K_4$ as an induced subgraph.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Let $G$ be a simple graph on $10$ vertices and $38$ edges. How do I prove that $K_4$ is the induced subgraph of G?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** There are only $7$ edges missing from $K_{10}$. Each missing edge can prevent up to $28$ different 4-vertex sets from inducing a $K_4$. How many 4-vertex sets are there?

Comment: Can you, please, explain why each edge can prevent 28 different 4-vertex sets from inducing a $K_4$? What is idea behind that?

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial with Turan's theorem, it tells us the maximum number of edges a graph without an induced $K_4$ can have is the number of edges in the Turan graph $T(10,3)$

In this case the Turan graph is the complete multipartite graph $K_{4,3,3}$. This graph has $45-6-3-3=33$ edges. So in fact it is true with as little as $34$ edges.

Comment: @:jorge how did you solved $T \left (10,3\right)$?

Comment: @sourav huh?${}{}{}$